# cordova/platforms/android/src/com/gae/scaffolder/plugin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:38: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using cordova cli 7.1.0 and cordova android 6.3.0.
This is cordova plugin I am using to build cordova project.
https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated.git

```
[javac] /Users/rashed/Documents/Development/prometheus/unionconnect-phone-1/cordova/platforms/android/src/com/gae/scaffolder/plugin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:38: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
[javac]if( remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
[javac]                          ^
[javac]class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: are you using custom build-extras.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when different versions of google-play-services components are available in your project.

Comment: I have removed all other plugins and just added this to test, but still getting the same error. I am not using build-extras.gradle. Here is my gradle file dependencies. dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

Comment: Here you can see firebase-core and firebase-version are different. Ideally, it should be the same. I think different plugins adding different versions.

Comment: I tried with same versions but still have the same issue. I also tried some other plugins as well like "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push" but have same error "[javac]class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found".

Comment: Can you check the build.gradle?  now as the build.gradle is auto-generated when you build the app  it might have updated the build.gradle

Comment: I am using the grunt script to change the build.gradle to make the same version before building the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200710/discussion-between-muhammad-rashid-and-swayangjit).